# Single word for "the one being stolen from"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, antonyms, analogy

By forming a noun from a verb, the person that steals is called a *stealer*. What do you call a person that is being stolen from?

Is there a corresponding noun that denotes the object of this action, as there is for verbs like *employ* (*employer, employee*), *call* (*caller*, *callee*), etc.?

Comment: Note that *stealer* is not as common as [*thief*, *robber*, or *burglar*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thief%2Crobber%2Cburglar%2Cstealer&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) although it is a valid word.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such single noun that I am aware of. We might say the **one stolen from** or the **victim**.

Colloquially you could find terms like the **mark** or the **patsy** but I would not recommend using them except under restricted circumstances and informal usage.

Comment: Under restricted circumstances. Do you mean in prison?

Comment: I think "mark" and "patsy" are more commonly used for the victim of a fraud than a simple theft. "Victim" is an appropriate word, but a victim can be the target of any crime, from trespassing to murder, so you'd have to make clear what the crime is in context.

Comment: @Jay I am just glad I did not marry a girl named Patsy, or would *we* be in for some bad luck.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could say "the robbed".

> Some of those people who were *robbed* by the banking system in 2008 are still having a hard time, eleven years later.

Comment: But it would be unusual to use it that way, and probably cause the reader to stumble.

Comment: The question is about stealing, not specifically robbery.

Answer (score 1):

Theft is a crime so legal words are appropriate. The legal word for the victim of theft (or robbery or burglary) is (in England) "the loser".

See https://www.sentencingcouncil.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/Theft-offences-definitive-guideline-Web.pdf